# swtbot failing when resetting workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I have a test like this

```
public class TesteSairApp extends GermantechTest {

    @Test
    public void testApp() throws Exception {
        SWTBotMenu file = bot.menu("Arquivo");
        bot.sleep(1000);

        SWTBotMenu clickSair = file.menu("Sair");
        bot.sleep(1000);

        SWTBotMenu menuClicado = clickSair.click();
        System.out.println(menuClicado);
        bot.sleep(1000);

        pass();
    }
```

which just quit the app.
After the app quit, I got this exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matchers
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.finder.SWTWorkbenchBot.editors(SWTWorkbenchBot.java:222)
    at ...`

If I remove the `bot.resetWorkbench();` from `@After` in `GermantehcTest`, the test passes...
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like a dependency issue. Did you include `org.hamcrest` in the manifest of your tests? 
If so take a look at the `org.hamcrest` bundle. As a guess the class 'org.hamcrest.Matchers' is missing there. 
Depending on the distribution of hamcrest you have chosen, this class might be missing (on purpose). Afaik it is missing in the `hamcrest-core-xy.jar`.
You could try to add the [Hamcrest additional library of matchers](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.hamcrest&version=1.1.0) to your target and your manifest.
If this works I would suggest to bake your own bundle of hamcrest-all, using [this](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/downloads/detail?name=hamcrest-all-1.3.jar&can=2&q=) as a base (I did not find a hamcrest-all as a bundle as a download).